# Google Map api works fast on Android browsers but is very slow in PC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Whatever I try to find the problem, I do not get any results! This is my JavaScript:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCHe4JT9sg9GES0XnscAbKXQbS-G4ZCwLc"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var inside = $("#inside").val();
function mapaccesspopup() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#MapAccessModal').modal('show');
        }, 300);
    };

    $(function () {
    $('#prt').on('click', function () {
        $('#dvMap').css("display", "block");
        $('#zxcv').css("display", "none");
       $('#radar').css("display", "none");
        $('#radar3').css("display", "none");
        $('#firstcap').css("display", "none");
        $('#secondcap').css("display", "none");
        $('#iok').css("display", "none");
        initMap();
        var swee = document.getElementById("access").value;
        if (swee == 'q') {
            mapaccesspopup();
            $('#access').val('w');
        }
    });
});
$(function () {
    $('#prtt').on('click', function () {
        $('#dvMap').css("display", "block");
        $('#zxcv').css("display", "none");
        $('#radar').css("display", "none");
        $('#radar3').css("display", "none");
        $('#firstcap').css("display", "none");
        $('#secondcap').css("display", "none");
        $('#iok').css("display", "none");
        initMap();
        var swee = document.getElementById("access").value;
        if (swee=='q') {
            mapaccesspopup();
            $('#access').val('w');
        }

    });
});

function initMap() {
    //read the parameter values you want to send to server
    var searchItem = $("#SearchItem").val();
    var jobs = $("#Jobs").val();
    var subid = $("#bluee").val();

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'),
        {
            zoom: 8
        });




    var url = "@Url.Action("AsMapAjax", "My")";


    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
        var latlngg = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);

        var mapOptions = {
            center: latlngg,
            zoom: 12,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        //You re Here

        var iconoMarca = "../../images/bnm.png";
        mymarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            map: map,
            icon: iconoMarca,
            position: latlngg,
            optimized: false,
            title:"شما اینجا هستید"

        });

        var numberMarkerImg = {
            url: '../../images/webresize2.png',
            labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(30, -6)
        };


        $.post(url, { SearchItem: searchItem, jobid: jobs, subid: subid }, function (res) {
            if (res.success) {
                var latLng;
                $.each(res.responseText, function (i, item) {
                    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.Lat, item.Lng);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        map: map,
                        icon: numberMarkerImg,

                        label: {
                            text: item.Title,
                            color: 'Black',
                            fontFamily: 'IranSans',
                            fontSize: '17'
                        },

                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                    });
                    @*var link=@Html.Raw("@Html.ActionLink(item.WdTitle, "+"Poster"+", new { id = Replace.SpaceToDash(item.WdTitle) + "+"__" + "item.WdId })");*@
                    //nahveye ferestadane meghdar be action
                    @*'@Url.Action("Display", "Customer")?uname=' + firstname + '&name=' + username;*@

                    @*var wdLink = '@Url.Action("Poster", "My")?id=' + item.Title.split(" ").join("-") + '__' + item.Id;
                    (function (marker, item) {
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                            infoWindow.setContent(item.Preamble);
                            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                            window.location.href = wdLink;

                        });
                    })*@
                    var wdLink = '@Url.Action("Poster", "My")?id=' + item.Title.split(" ").join("-") + '__' + item.Id;

                    var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
'<div id="siteNotice">' +
'</div>' +
'<div  id="firstHeading">' + item.Title + '</div>' +
'<div id="bodyContent">' +
'<p><b>' + item.Preamble + '</b></p>' +
'<p><h4> <a href="'+ wdLink+'">' +
'اطلاعات بیشتر</a></h4> ' +
'</p>' +
'</div>' +
'</div>';



          },];


                    var sourceLocation = { lat: p.coords.latitude, lng: p.coords.longitude };
                    var destinationLocations = 
                 [{ lat: item.Lat, lng: item.Lng }];
                    var directionsService;
                    var directionsDisplay;
                    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                        map: map,
                        markerOptions: {
                            visible: false
                        }
                    });
                    function markerClicked(destinationLocation) {
                        var directionsRequest = {
                            origin: sourceLocation,
                            destination: destinationLocation,
                            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
                        };

                        directionsService.route(directionsRequest, handleDirectionResults);
                    }

                    function handleDirectionResults(result, status) {
                        if (status === 'OK') {
                            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
                        } else {
                            console.log(status);
                        }
                    }

                    function createDestinationMarkers() {
                        destinationLocations.forEach(function(location, index) {

                            marker.addListener('click', function () {
                                markerClicked(location);
                            });

                        })
                    }


                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentString
                    });
                    marker.addListener('click', function () {
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        createDestinationMarkers()

                        //flightPath.setMap(map);

                    });

                     (marker, item);
                    ////
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $(window).resize(function () {
                            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                        });
                        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                    });


                });
                map.setCenter(latlngg);
            }
        });
    });
}

</script>
```

You can [visit this website](https://www.khadamatresan.com/) to see this problem.

Comment: Is it the initial map rendering that is slow, or a scroll operation? Have you tried cutting your code down to see what part of the code might affect the speed?

Comment: Thank you for help ,every time After loading. This is the main problem with Google's geolocation.this part=>  var latlngg = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude)...

Comment: It works well in Android browsers and has no problems